# alias ls="ls --color" in RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to implement `alias`-like functionality in JavaScript with `RegExp`?

```
ALIAS = [{pattern: /^ls[$ ]/, replace: 'ls --color '}]
s = 'ls /'
alias = function(t) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ALIAS.length; i++) {
        t = t.replace(ALIAS[i].pattern, ALIAS[i].replace)
    }
    return t
}
console.log(alias('ls'))
console.log(alias('ls /'))
console.log(alias('lsusb'))
console.log(alias('lsCPU'))
```

incorrect output:

```
~ ls
~ ls --color /
~ lsusb
~ lsCPU
```

expected output:

```
~ ls --color
~ ls --color /
~ lsusb
~ lsCPU
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect. `/^ls[$ ]/` matches `ls` followed by a literal `$` or a space. `$` is *not* an anchor inside a character class, `[]`.

You want `/^ls\b/`, that is, `ls` followed by a word boundary:

```
 ALIAS = [{pattern: /^ls\b/, replace: 'ls --color'}]
```